# email sent when case is created

Tags: workflow

I have a problem in my production. When a case is created by end user for a specific product, according to assignment rules it is assigned to a particular queue. But as soon as the case is assigned to the queue, automatically response mail is sent to the user. Because of this the case status is getting changed to updated. I have checked all the workflows.
The email alert is sent just like when the end user sends response to the case.

Comment: You need to revisit your workflow. It is unclear about your issue and your ask.

Comment: @Shantanu,  the user who created the case is automatically getting acknoloedgement mail for the case created. I need to figure out due to what this is happening

Comment: This is because of auto-response rule, user is getting notified

Comment: Auto response rules are setup for all king of products. The response is sent only when the support agent clicks on "Send Response button". It should not fire unless it is done.